# How to get rid of blank white screen in expo-go app that becomes unresponsive without error?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am trying to get into App Development because I want to learn something new and build an app that I have an idea for, and I have been following the "Build and Deploy a React Native App" video by javascript mastery on youtube.

Now I am stuck for the third time with my expo-app on my android phone only displaying a completely blank white screen, while also not allowing me to access the settings by shaking my phone. The expo-go app becomes unresponsive.
I had this once before, and after trying for a while to fix it or find an error in my code, I just started the whole project over, Re-writing all my code.
It always happens after I stop working on it for the day, leave it in a functional state, and come back to it the next day.
In VS Code, I get no errors, bundling always completes without any issue. I also updated my reac-native version from  react-native@0.73.2 to 0.73.4 because I kept getting a message informing me I should do that because of compatibility with my expo version.

Im very new to app and web-development, so I am sorry if this question is stupid, but I cant find anything on google that relates to my problem in any meaningful way and I dont know where to start with debugging.
I dont even know what I can supply you with to help you better understand the situation.

here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react_native_jobs2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "expo": "^50.0.1",
    "expo-constants": "~15.4.5",
    "expo-font": "^11.10.2",
    "expo-linking": "~6.2.2",
    "expo-router": "~3.4.3",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.26.3",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.4",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.10",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Maybe there is an issue in _layout.js:

```
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import { useCallback } from "react";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

const Layout = () => {
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    DMBold: require("../assets/fonts/DMSans-Bold.ttf"),
    DMMedium: require("../assets/fonts/DMSans-Medium.ttf"),
    DMRegular: require("../assets/fonts/DMSans-Regular.ttf"),
  });

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (fontsLoaded) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [fontsLoaded]);

  if (!fontsLoaded) return null;

  return <Stack onLayout={onLayoutRootView} />;
};

export default Layout;
```

or in Welcome.jsx (here I just found out about the difference between ' and ` and fixed that, but still not working):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { 
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image, 
  FlatList
} from 'react-native';
import {useRouter} from 'expo-router';

import styles from './welcome.style'
import {icons, SIZES } from '../../../constants';

const jobTypes = ["Full-time", "Part-time", "Contractor"];

const Welcome = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [activeJobType, setActiveJobType] = useState('Full-time')
  
  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.userName}>Hello Adrian</Text>
        <Text style={styles.welcomeMessage}>Find your perfect job</Text>
      </View>
      
      <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
        <View style={styles.searchhWrapper}>
          <TextInput 
          style={styles.searchInput}
          value=""
          onChange={() => {}}
          placeholder="What are you lookingfor?"
          />
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.searchBtn} onPress={() => {}}>
          <Image
          source={icons.search}
          resizeMode='contain'
          style={styles.searchBtnImage}
          />

        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.tabsContainer}>
        <FlatList
        data={jobTypes}
        renderItem={({item})=> (
          <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.tab(activeJobType, item)}
          onPress={()=> {
            setActiveJobType(item);
            router.push(`/search/${item}`)
          }}>
            <Text style={styles.tabText(activeJobType, item)}>{item}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
  )}
  keyExtractor={item => item}
  contentContainerStyle={{columnGap: SIZES.small}}
  horizontal
  />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Welcome
```

Tried finding Code errors and updating react-native. Resulted in no change - code just stopped working overnight 3 days in a row.